# Why does rmdir (the system call) only work on empty directory?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, system-calls

Is it not possible to atomically unlink the directory from its parent's inode? Is there any historical reason behind this?

Comment: On the contrary, `rmdir` only works on a **empty** directory. It throws an error ENOTEMPTY if the directory contains any actual entries (i.e. other than . and ..). The "why" is because it does not know where to put safely any files that are present, and it prefers you not to lose a whole directory/file tree by accident.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Nope. I meant it can be done atomically since it should be doable with only one inode write (so it doesn't matter whether we're using a journal fs or a shadowing fs). So I don't know what value this restriction adds to the fs.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Oops that was a typo. And try not to cause any accident makes sense. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

```c
int rmdir(const char *pathname);
```

is a [system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html), conforming to  POSIX.1-2001. Now imagine a situation when you want this system call not to delete just a single directory but all the subdirectories and files within.

1. You'll have to add this logic to the kernel which is not an easy feat and by doing so you'll bloat the kernel
2. The operation becomes non-deterministic in terms of execution time
3. There are dozens of ways it can fail handling of which in the kernel doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: as for point 2: I don't think `rmdir()` or next to any other file-handing system call is very deterministic now either. The FS could over the network, or the disk very loaded.

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature  not a bug!

One can easily remove empty directories with `rmdir *`, while leaving non-empty directories alone. This is a system management practice I use often.

There is `rm -rf` to delete whole directory trees (all files and subdirectories).